# Usage LWC in flow returns error when package creation

Tags: lightning-web-components, managed-package, screen-flow, lightning-button, issue

I used the LWC component which works on orgs of all types (sandboxes, scratches, etc) and used in screen flow.
There were no errors when I've ever deployed to these orgs.
BUT

When I've tried to create 2nd gen package version and received the error:

```
(Flow_Name) duplicate value found: <unknown> duplicates value on record with id: <unknown>
Flow_Name: duplicate value found: <unknown> duplicates value on record with id: <unknown>
```

All attempts to find problem lead to this LWC component and it gives the error even it is the only one appearance.
After I deleted LWC component usage - all works.

Part of flow below:

```
<screens>
       ...
            <name>Client_Info_Yes</name>
            <extensionName>c:navigateButton</extensionName>
            <fieldType>ComponentInstance</fieldType>
       ...
</screens>
```

Could someone help with this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The component reference in your flow is currently:

```
<extensionName>c:navigateButton</extensionName>
```

This needs to be updated to use the namespace prefix for your package. If your package namespace is "abc", update to:

```
<extensionName>abc:navigateButton</extensionName>
```

The prefix `c` is the no-namespace namespace placeholder.

Comment: It works, it is perfect but ambiguous solution. Thanks a lot!
Could you please share a link to documentation where I can read about this?

Comment: This is a "feature" of flows in packaging. It does not correctly handle namespaces. It is fine if you develop for packaging using namespaced scratch orgs, but does mean you have to mess about with the prefix if you take the metadata from one place to another where the namespaces are different.

Comment: This is not (yet) documented anywhere I have found. Not even on the partner forums.